# How do show my javascript date object in users local time, across various browsers?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a  project where Im reading JSON data and it contains a date string that Im getting in the following syntax:

```
2015-09-16T10:00:00
```

I need to take that string and make it a date object and have it be in the format MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss and make sure its in the viewing users timezone automatically

I have the following function so far, but the issues I see are that

1.) I have to add the 'T' between the date and time in my string or firefox and IE9 tells me NaN and the date object I'm creating ISN'T A VALID DATE. (not sure why, but OK, I can live with adding the 'T')

2.) The bigger issue/problem: Firefox currently has this working and it shows the correct time for my time zone (10:00:00)... but in IE9, chrome and safari, it shows 6:00:00.

Question: How do I get the final output date string to ALWAYS be in the correct time (based on users time zone) across browsers without need of an external library?

Heres the function in its current state:

```
function cleanDateTime(thisdt) {
    var d = new Date(thisdt) // CONVERT THE PASSED STRING TO A DATE OBJECT
    var cleanedDate = '';

    // GET ALL THE DATE PARTS... 
    var MM = (d.getMonth()+1).toString();
    var DD = d.getDate().toString();
    var YYYY = d.getFullYear().toString();
    var hh = d.getHours().toString();
    var mm = (d.getMinutes()<10?'0':'').toString() + d.getMinutes().toString();
    var ss = (d.getSeconds()<10?'0':'').toString() + d.getSeconds().toString();

    // BUILD THE FINAL DATE STRING FROM THOSE PARTS...
    var cleanedDate = ( MM + '/' + DD + '/' + YYYY + ' ' + hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss )

    return cleanedDate;
```

};

and I call this function like so...

```
console.log ( cleanDateTime('2015-09-16T10:00:00') );
```

** UPDATE / PROBLEM SOLVED ( Thanks achan )...

As suggested, Im now using moment.js and I call the function like so to have it show correct time across browsers:

```
console.log ( cleanDateTime(moment("2015-09-16T10:00:00")) );
```

Comment: you may want to check momentjs.com

Comment: @achan Awesome, was trying to avoid a library / framework but hey, now it works reliably.   So glad to have a solution and generally speaking moment.js just seems to be the cure for almost ANY sort of javascript date issues, so thanks and Im sure I'll be using it a LOT.  Thanks again, post as answer and you get my vote.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks for your vote..

momentjs.org

this is also my favorite javascript library (underscore)

Comment: Providing a link to the library is barely an answer

Comment: I know I said without a library, but in a broader sense, this will be helpful (moment.js) for some other date handling I'll have for the project in general, so I'll let moment.js do its magic.

Comment: Suggestions for libraries should be added as comments. At the very least, you could show how to use the library to parse the string and format the date.

Comment: @RobG he originally put it as a comment and the OP asked him to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to manually split the datestring and pass the [*individual*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) parts of the date to the `Date` constructor and make any timezone adjustments in the process, again, manually. Or use moment.js as achan suggested in the comments.

```
var ds = '2015-09-16T10:00:00';
var dsSplit = ds.split('T');
var dateArr = dsSplit[0].split('-');
var timeArr = dsSplit[1].split(':');
var yr = dateArr[0], mon = dateArr[1], day = dateArr[2];
var hr = timeArr[0], min = timeArr[1], sec = timeArr[2];
var date = new Date(yr, mon, day, hr, min, sec);
```

Comment: You're welcome. I should also probably mention that if you use babel then destructuring assignment makes the process a lot shorter.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here. Firstly, never pass strings to the Date constructor because its parsing of strings is unreliable to day the least. The string "2015-09-16T10:00:00" is treated as follows:

1. In ECMA-262 ed 3 parsing is entirely implementation dependent, early versions of IE will not parse ISO 8601 format dates
2. In ES5, it will be treated as UTC
3. In ECMAScript 2015, it will be treated as local (which is also consistent with ISO 8601)

So unless you want to leave it to chance, always manually parse date strings.

Given that you can be sure that the string is a valid date, parsing it per ECMAScript 2015 only requires a couple of lines of code. The following functions create a Date based on either UTC or local time, depending on which you want. Of course it's pretty easy to make them one function with a toggle that looks for a trailing Z and uses UTC.

```js
/** @param {string} s - date string in ISO 8601 format
**  @returns {Date} - Date from parsing string as a local date time
**/
function parseISODateLocal(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]);
}
    
document.write(parseISODateLocal('2015-09-16T10:00:00') + '<br>');

/** @param {string} s - date string in ISO 8601 format
**  @returns {Date} - Date from parsing string as a UTC date time
**/
function parseISODateUTC(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]));
}

document.write(parseISODateUTC('2015-09-16T10:00:00'));
```

Presenting a date as 9/6/2015 10:00:00 on the web is likely to be very confusing for many since the vast majority of the world's population will expect the order to be day, month, year. Far better to use an unambiguous format using the month name like September 6, 2015 or 6-Sep-2015 or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the indepth info @RobG.  Always good to have reasoning and not just settle for a quick answer.  In this use case its for a monitoring tool for our internal staff on a backend process so the date format works for our internal needs but agreed, if used for general public on the web it could indeed be confusing.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did mine...

```
var d, m, day, yr;
d = new Date();
day = d.getDate();
m = d.getMonth();
yr = d.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("dateObj").value = m + "/" + day + "/" + yr;
```